# Google chart shows dots not line chart

Tags: charts, google-visualization

Working on my line chart and very confused why it shows dots and not lines between the dots. So hope someone can help me with my problem. Thanks!

[image]

Google chart code, I can paste the whole code with sql query and so if needed:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">


    Temperatur = document.getElementById('Temperatur'), 
    Badende_Per_Time = document.getElementById('Badende_Per_Time'),
    Luft_Temperatur = document.getElementById('Luft_Temperatur');
    FrittKlor = document.getElementById('FrittKlor');
    BundetKlor = document.getElementById('BundetKlor');
    TotalKlor = document.getElementById('TotalKlor');
    PH = document.getElementById('PH');
    AutoKlor = document.getElementById('AutoKlor');
    AutoPh = document.getElementById('AutoPh');
    AutoTemperatur = document.getElementById('AutoTemperatur');

      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    Temperatur.onchange = drawChart;
    Badende_Per_Time.onchange = drawChart;
    Luft_Temperatur.onchange = drawChart;
    FrittKlor.onchange = drawChart;
    BundetKlor.onchange = drawChart;  
    TotalKlor.onchange = drawChart; 
    PH.onchange = drawChart;    
    AutoKlor.onchange = drawChart;
    AutoPh.onchange = drawChart;
    AutoTemperatur.onchange = drawChart;


      function drawChart() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?=$jsonTable?>);

        var options = {
         width: 1100, height: 520, 
          title: 'Diagram',
          curveType: 'function', 
           legend: { position: 'bottom' },
           pointSize: 5,
        vAxis: {title: "Verdi", titleTextStyle: {italic: false}},
        hAxis: {title: "Tid", titleTextStyle: {italic: false}},
        explorer: { actions: ['dragToZoom', 'rightClickToReset'], 
                    axis: 'both' },

            focusTarget: 'category',


       };

       if (!AutoTemperatur.checked) data.removeColumn(10);
       if (!AutoPh.checked) data.removeColumn(9);
       if (!AutoKlor.checked) data.removeColumn(8);
       if (!PH.checked) data.removeColumn(7);
       if (!TotalKlor.checked) data.removeColumn(6);
       if (!BundetKlor.checked) data.removeColumn(5); 
       if (!FrittKlor.checked) data.removeColumn(4); 
       if (!Luft_Temperatur.checked) data.removeColumn(3); 
       if (!Badende_Per_Time.checked) data.removeColumn(2);
       if (!Temperatur.checked) data.removeColumn(1);

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);

      }
    </script>
```

Code:

```
$sth = sqlsrv_query($conn,"

            SELECT routines.date, routines.time, 
            SUM( CASE WHEN measurements.title =  'T_Temperatur' THEN CAST( REPLACE( routines.value,  ',',  '.' ) AS DECIMAL( 18, 2 ) ) ELSE NULL END) AS Temperatur,
            SUM( CASE WHEN measurements.title =  'T_Badende_per_Time' THEN CAST( REPLACE( routines.value,  ',',  '.' ) AS DECIMAL( 18, 2 ) ) ELSE NULL END) AS Badende_Per_Time,
            SUM( CASE WHEN measurements.title =  'T_Luft_Temperatur' THEN CAST( REPLACE( routines.value,  ',',  '.' ) AS DECIMAL( 18, 2 ) ) ELSE NULL END) AS Luft_Temperatur,
            SUM( CASE WHEN measurements.title =  'M_Fritt_Klor' THEN CAST( REPLACE( routines.value,  ',',  '.' ) AS DECIMAL( 18, 2 ) ) ELSE NULL END) AS FrittKlor,
            SUM( CASE WHEN measurements.title =  'M_Bundet_Klor' THEN CAST( REPLACE( routines.value,  ',',  '.' ) AS DECIMAL( 18, 2 ) ) ELSE NULL END) AS BundetKlor,
            SUM( CASE WHEN measurements.title =  'M_Total_Klor' THEN CAST( REPLACE( routines.value,  ',',  '.' ) AS DECIMAL( 18, 2 ) ) ELSE NULL END) AS TotalKlor,
            SUM( CASE WHEN measurements.title =  'M_PH' THEN CAST( REPLACE( routines.value,  ',',  '.' ) AS DECIMAL( 18, 2 ) ) ELSE NULL END) AS PH,
            SUM( CASE WHEN measurements.title =  'M_Auto_Klor' THEN CAST( REPLACE( routines.value,  ',',  '.' ) AS DECIMAL( 18, 2 ) ) ELSE NULL END) AS AutoKlor,
            SUM( CASE WHEN measurements.title =  'M_Auto_PH' THEN CAST( REPLACE( routines.value,  ',',  '.' ) AS DECIMAL( 18, 2 ) ) ELSE NULL END) AS AutoPh,
            SUM( CASE WHEN measurements.title =  'A_Auto_Temperatur' THEN CAST( REPLACE( routines.value,  ',',  '.' ) AS DECIMAL( 18, 2 ) ) ELSE NULL END) AS AutoTemperatur
            FROM routines
            INNER JOIN measure_routine ON routines.id = measure_routine.routine_id
            INNER JOIN measurements ON measure_routine.measure_id = measurements.id
            INNER JOIN pools ON measure_routine.pool_id = pools.id

            WHERE routines.date between '".$fraDato."' AND '".$tilDato."'
            AND (pools.name = '".$basseng."' OR pools.name = 'Svommehall') 
            AND routines.time between '".$fraTid."' AND '".$tilTid."'

            GROUP BY routines.date, routines.time
            ORDER BY routines.date, routines.time;

        ;");

        if( $sth === false ) {
             die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        }

       $rows = array();
       $flag = true;
       $table = array();
       $table['cols'] = array(

       array('label' => 'routines.date' & 'routines.time', 'type' => 'datetime'),
       array('label' => 'Temperatur', 'type' => 'number'),  
       array('label' => 'Badende_Per_Time', 'type' => 'number'),
       array('label' => 'Luft_Temperatur', 'type' => 'number'), 
       array('label' => 'FrittKlor', 'type' => 'number'),
       array('label' => 'BundetKlor', 'type' => 'number'),   
       array('label' => 'TotalKlor', 'type' => 'number'), 
       array('label' => 'PH', 'type' => 'number'),
       array('label' => 'AutoKlor', 'type' => 'number'),
       array('label' => 'AutoPh', 'type' => 'number'),
       array('label' => 'AutoTemperatur', 'type' => 'number'),

        );

        $rows = array();


        while($r = sqlsrv_fetch_array  ($sth)) 
        {

            //$temp = array();
            // assumes dates are in the format "yyyy-MM-dd"

            $dateString = $r['date'];
            $year = $dateString->format('Y');
            $month = $dateString->format('m') -1;
            $day = $dateString->format('d');

            // assumes time is in the format "hh:mm:ss"

            $timeString = $r['time'];
            $hours = $timeString->format('G');
            $minutes = $timeString->format('i');
            $seconds = $timeString->format('s');

            $temp = array();
            $temp[] = array('v' => "Date($year, $month, $day, $hours, $minutes, $seconds)"); 
            $temp[] = array('v' => $r['Temperatur']);
            $temp[] = array('v' => $r['Badende_Per_Time']);
            $temp[] = array('v' => $r['Luft_Temperatur']);
            $temp[] = array('v' => $r['FrittKlor']);
            $temp[] = array('v' => $r['BundetKlor']);
            $temp[] = array('v' => $r['TotalKlor']);
            $temp[] = array('v' => $r['PH']);
            $temp[] = array('v' => $r['AutoKlor']);
            $temp[] = array('v' => $r['AutoPh']);
            $temp[] = array('v' => $r['AutoTemperatur']);

            $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);

        } 

             $table['rows'] = $rows;
             $jsonTable = json_encode($table, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
            //echo $jsonTable;
```

$jsonTable:

```
00)"},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":28.5}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2014, 4, 08, 6, 00, 00)"},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":28.5}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2014, 4, 08, 7, 58, 33)"},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":1.94},{"v":0.39},{"v":2.33},{"v":7.19},{"v":2.13},{"v":7.05},{"v":null}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2014, 4, 08, 7, 59, 39)"},{"v":28.1},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2014, 4, 08, 7, 59, 59)"},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":28.5}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2014, 4, 08, 8, 01, 04)"},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":27.8},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2014, 4, 08, 8, 02, 20)"},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2014, 4, 08, 8, 40, 20)"},{"v":null},{"v":0},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2014, 4, 08, 9, 30, 18)"},{"v":null},{"v":33},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2014, 4, 08, 9, 59, 59)"},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":28.44}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2014, 4, 08, 10, 38, 34)"},{"v":null},{"v":36},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2014, 4, 08, 11, 23, 02)"},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":1.94},{"v":0.39},{"v":2.33},{"v":7.21},{"v":2.15},{"v":7.08},{"v":null}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2014, 4, 08, 11, 36, 40)"},{"v":null},{"v":0},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2014, 4, 08, 12, 00, 00)"},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":28.44}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2014, 4, 08, 12, 30, 40)"},{"v":null},{"v":6},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2014, 4, 08, 13, 33, 47)"},{"v":null},{"v":0},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2014, 4, 08, 14, 22, 46)"},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":1.99},{"v":0.29},{"v":2.28},{"v":7.22},{"v":2.1},{"v":7.01},{"v":null}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2014, 4, 08, 14, 26, 30)"},{"v":null},{"v":3},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2014, 4, 08, 14, 39, 00)"},{"v":28.2},{"v":0},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2014, 4, 08, 14, 41, 53)"},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":26.7},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2014, 4, 08, 15, 45, 49)"},{"v":null},{"v":17},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2014, 4, 08, 16, 34, 38)"},{"v":null},{"v":38},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2014, 4, 08, 17, 16, 13)"},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":1.89},{"v":0.44},{"v":2.33},{"v":7.17},{"v":2.08},{"v":7.08},{"v":null}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2014, 4, 08, 17, 24, 04)"},{"v":null},{"v":62},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null}]}]}
```

Comment: Please dump* $jsonTable. Sorry :). In order to replicate the problem I would like to have the contents of jsonTable. Alernatively you can start a fiddle yourself, maybe you will see the problem yourself if you refactor some.

Comment: Your `$jsonTable` dump looks like you copied the second half of the string, can you update with the full string?

Comment: From what I've been able to tease out of your data, your data points have `null` values in between them, which breaks the line in the charts by default.  You can override this by setting the chart's `interpolateNulls` option to `true`.

Comment: Dude! How can I thank you ??? That worked PERFECT! THANKS ALOT!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [asgallant's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23540070/google-chart-shows-dots-not-line-chart#comment36129872_23540070):

> From what I've been able to tease out of your data, your data points have `null` values in between them, which breaks the line in the charts by default. You can override this by setting the chart's `interpolateNulls` option to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

1.You can use data.sort([{column: 0}]); for sorting it based on x-axis, Here column:0 indicatesx-axis.
[google chart doc for sorting](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable_getSortedRows)

2.If the value you are trying to pass is through some xml or json and it has null values inside, It will not plot properly and will be scattered or as dotted lines in line graph so to plot them, have a condition to remove all null values and then it will plot correctly.